# Why are the custom delimiters in vuejs not working?

Tags: vue.js, jekyll, vuetify.js

I'm using vuejs with Jekyll, and want to use custom delimiters for vue, because jekyll use the same one.

This i for a static site. I use vuejs v2.6.10, vuetify v2.0.0beta-4 and jekyll v3.8.0.

This is a part of my component:

```html
<v-card-text style="min-height: 300px;">
            <div class="pr-3 pl-3">
              <h2 class="text-xs-center mb-2">${ teaser.title }</h2>
              <v-divider class="mb-3"></v-divider>
              <p style="text-align: left;">${ teaser.text } <a class="primary--text" style="text-decoration: none;" href="#">Weiterlesen</a></p>
            </div>
          </v-card-text>

        </v-card>
      </v-flex>

    </v-layout>
```

in my layout i just get it as plain text like "${teaset.title}"

Also i don't get any error or so.

Comment: I believe the syntax is `{{ teaser.title }}` for jekyll or vue

Comment: why are you using jekyll and vue?

Comment: because i made the frontent with vuetify but I must use jekyll because of my company so yeah i try to combine these two.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render your variable values at html part, do this instead:

```html
    <v-card-text style="min-height: 300px;">
            <div class="pr-3 pl-3">
              <h2 class="text-xs-center mb-2"> {{ teaser.title }} </h2>
              <v-divider class="mb-3"></v-divider>
              <p style="text-align: left;"> {{ teaser.text }} <a class="primary--text" style="text-decoration: none;" href="#">Weiterlesen</a></p>
            </div>
          </v-card-text>

        </v-card>
      </v-flex>

    </v-layout>
```

Just remove the `$` and use double `"{{" and "}}"`

Comment: Ik the syntax tho but i want to use these custom dilimeters because vue and jekyll got the same so it is getting kinda confusing.

Comment: like the doc says: "This option is only available in the full build, with in-browser compilation." what does that mean :/

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters

Comment: did you define your delimiters?? Look at this link: https://blog.liplex.de/using-vue-js-template-delimiters-in-twig/

Comment: this one too https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5697

Comment: okay i see i did read that issue on github so that means i can't use the custom delimiters in a .vue file :/